# how would you sort this list of router interfaces?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I have tried sorting this list using

```
sorted(list_of_interfaces, key = lambda x:x.split(':')[0].split('/')[2])
```

however i do not get the result i want.

Basically the first interfaces should be `xe-0/0/0:0` followed by `xe-0/0/0:1`, `xe-0/0/0:2` and `xe-0/0/0:3`. From there the next interface should be `xe-0/0/1:0` and so on. For some reason my code puts `xe-0/0/10` right after `xe-0/0/1` as shown below. Any suggestion?

```
xe-0/0/0:3
xe-0/0/0:2
xe-0/0/0:1
xe-0/0/0:0
xe-0/0/1:1
xe-0/0/1:3
xe-0/0/1:0
xe-0/0/1:2
xe-0/0/10:0
xe-0/0/10:3
xe-0/0/10:1
xe-0/0/10:2
xe-0/0/11:2
xe-0/0/11:1
xe-0/0/11:3
xe-0/0/11:0
xe-0/0/12:2
xe-0/0/12:1
xe-0/0/12:0
xe-0/0/12:3
xe-0/0/13:2
xe-0/0/13:3
xe-0/0/13:1
xe-0/0/13:0
xe-0/0/14:1
xe-0/0/14:0
xe-0/0/14:3
xe-0/0/14:2
xe-0/0/15:2
xe-0/0/15:0
xe-0/0/15:1
xe-0/0/15:3
xe-0/0/2:1
xe-0/0/2:3
xe-0/0/2:0
xe-0/0/2:2
xe-0/0/3:1
xe-0/0/3:2
xe-0/0/3:3
xe-0/0/3:0
xe-0/0/4:2
xe-0/0/4:3
xe-0/0/4:0
xe-0/0/4:1
xe-0/0/5:1
xe-0/0/5:0
xe-0/0/5:2
xe-0/0/5:3
xe-0/0/6:1
xe-0/0/6:0
xe-0/0/6:3
xe-0/0/6:2
xe-0/0/7:1
xe-0/0/7:0
xe-0/0/7:2
xe-0/0/7:3
xe-0/0/8:0
xe-0/0/8:1
xe-0/0/8:3
xe-0/0/8:2
xe-0/0/9:1
xe-0/0/9:0
xe-0/0/9:2
xe-0/0/9:3
```

Comment: Write a function that accepts one item and return a tuple of the parts of that item where the numbers are integers (`'xe-0/0/0:3'` -> `('xe', 0, 0, 0, 3)`). Then give this function as the `key` keyword argument to the `sort()` or `sorted()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sorting lists of strings, but want to sort them as lists of integers.